# How to transpose columns into rows and ensure repetition of rows accordingly in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, transpose, data-transform

How to transpose the columns and ensure that rows are repeated accordingly?

Dataset has the following data :-

| Date | Year | Month | Day | USD | EUR | JPY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1994 | 1994 | 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 5 |
| 1/1/1995 | 1995 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 30 | 10 |

The expected output is :-

| Date | Year | Month | Day | Currency | Currency/CCY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/1994 | 1994 | 1 | 1 | USD | 10 |
| 1/1/1994 | 1994 | 1 | 1 | EUR | 20 |
| 1/1/1994 | 1994 | 1 | 1 | JPY | 5 |
| 1/1/1995 | 1995 | 1 | 1 | USD | 12 |
| 1/1/1995 | 1995 | 1 | 1 | EUR | 30 |
| 1/1/1995 | 1995 | 1 | 1 | JPY | 10 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished quickly and easily using <kbd>POWER QUERY</kbd>. To achieve this using the said procedure, follow the steps:

---

- First convert the source ranges into a table and name it accordingly, for this example I have named it as `Table1`

---

- Next, open a blank query from <kbd>Data</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Get & Transform Data</kbd> --> <kbd>Get Data</kbd> --> <kbd>From Other Sources</kbd> --> <kbd>Blank Query</kbd>

---

- The above lets the <kbd>Power Query</kbd> window opens, now from <kbd>Home</kbd> Tab --> <kbd>Advanced Editor</kbd> --> And paste the following <kbd>M-Code</kbd> by removing whatever you see, and press <kbd>Done</kbd>

---

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date", "Year", "Month", "Day"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Attribute", "Currency"}, {"Value", "Currency/CCY"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

---

[image]

---

- Lastly, to import it back to <kbd>Excel</kbd> --> Click on <kbd>Close & Load</kbd> or <kbd>Close & Load To</kbd> --> The first one which clicked shall create a <kbd>New Sheet</kbd> with the required output while the latter will prompt a window asking you where to place the result.

---

[image]

---

Or, Using **`Excel Formulas`** to **`UNPIVOT OTHER COLUMNS`**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A6</kbd>

```
=LET(
    _data, A1:G3,
    _matrixOne, TAKE(_data,,4),
    _matrixTwo, DROP(_data,,4),
    _headerOne, TAKE(_matrixOne,1),
    _headerTwo, TAKE(_matrixTwo,1),
    _bodyOne, DROP(_matrixOne,1),
    _bodyTwo, DROP(_matrixTwo,1),
    _diemn, ROWS(_bodyOne)*COLUMNS(_headerTwo),
    _rowDiemn, MOD(SEQUENCE(_diemn,,0),COLUMNS(_headerTwo))+1,
    _rowDiemx, INT((SEQUENCE(_diemn,,0))/COLUMNS(_headerTwo))+1,
    _transformHeader, INDEX(_headerTwo,_rowDiemn),
    _transformMatrixOne, INDEX(_bodyOne,_rowDiemx,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(_matrixOne))),
    _transformMatrixTwo, INDEX(_bodyTwo,SEQUENCE(_diemn,,0)/COLUMNS(_headerTwo)+1,_rowDiemn),
    _topHeader, HSTACK(_headerOne,"Currency","Currency/CCY"),
    _bottomBody, HSTACK(_transformMatrixOne,_transformHeader,_transformMatrixTwo),
    VSTACK(_topHeader,_bottomBody))
```

---